# Continuous integration and software versioning

Tags: c#, continuous-integration

I like the idea of automatically versioning my builds but I'm not sure what the right way is to get the AssemblyInfo.cs change back into source control (or should it not go into source control?). Is this something the CI server should be committing automatically for each build?

Using Bamboo at the moment.

Comment: What CI server do you use? The answer will vary depending on Bamboo, TeamCity, TeamFoundation Server.

Comment: @JoePhilllips - have edited my answer with a link indicating how build number can be set in artifact.

Answer (score 1):

We are using Teamcity as our CI server, and it comes with a feature called [AssemblyInfo patcher](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD65/AssemblyInfo+Patcher)

What this does, is temporarily add the teamcity build number in Assemblyinfo.cs, build generate the artifact and then revert the change. This way the generated artifact has the same version as the build number.

Source control can have the assemblyinfo.cs version entry as the current revision the developers are working on, with '*' as the build number. This can be updated after every release.

**Edit 1:**
Since you are using Bamboo, [here](http://itrathnasekara.blogspot.in/2011/05/setting-assembly-version-automatically.html) is a link that describes one way of setting the build number in the generated artifact in bamboo, without having to check-in the AssemblyInfo.cs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of confused by your question. If you want the changes to persist you'll have to commit AssemblyInfo.cs after it gets edited by the build job. However, most build systems attempting to solve these problems do not persist the changes. They simply check out the file and edit the local version before kicking off the build task.

Comment: "most build systems..." In that system, how do you handle when you want to go back in history and rebuild a certain version from source control? If nothing was committed, how do you know what point to "pull" from?